# How to solve this kind of unknown error of get storage

Tags: flutter, get, storage

I'd faced this unknown error where the getStorage have problem to write the data. Is anybody ever met this type of error. Hope somebody can help me.

```dart
    String? nullCheck(String? state, String? data, String device, String key) {
    var checkData;

    if (state != null) {
      checkData = data;
      getStorage.write(device + key, data);

      return checkData;
    }
    if (state == null) {
      checkData = getStorage.read(device + key);
    }
    return checkData;
  }
```

the error as in this picture:
[unknown error of get storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoVOK.png)

Comment: yeah, uhh, that's... not an error. That's just code, you see the red dot to the left on the yellow line? The one surrounded by a yellow sideways "house" in your picture? Try clicking it, it's a breakpoint, it's a debugging tool, it stops the code so you can take a look at it. that's what's stopping the program, it isn't an error, once you click it, run the code again.

Comment: Thanks for the comment haha I just revert the code and it's working fine back. Thank you anyways